# How to layout differently sized images within a container with a constrained size?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have three images of different sizes which I would like to layout side-by-side within a responsive container that has a max-width. e.g.

[Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmgPi.png)

The HTML for the images is as follows:

```
<ul class="break-out ideation-sketches">
   <li><img src="images/work-blue-ideation1.jpg" alt="Ideation sketches"></li>
   <li><img src="images/work-blue-ideation2.jpg" alt="More ideation sketches"></li>
   <li><img src="images/work-blue-ideation3.jpg" alt="Yet more ideation sketches"></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried making the ul a Flexbox and constraining it's size using max-width, but the images force the container to be wider than the page. With display:grid I was able to constrain the size of the container, but I wasn't able to get the center image to match the height of the first and last images on either side.

To summarise:

1. Add a number of images of various differing sizes and aspect ratios
2. Have them display side-by-side within a container
3. The container should shrink to the width of the browser and not extend beyond it's max-width
4. The height of the container is not known in advance - it adapts so as to accommodate the images
5. The images should resize proportionally so as to fill the container while maintaining their aspect ratio.
6. Each image should have the same height as its siblings, and where necessary a different width so as to maintain its own aspect ratio.

Comment: Not sure I’ve fully grasped the scenario, but do you know the aspect ratios of each image in advance?

Comment: @AHaworth Ideally, I'd like to use images of any aspect ratio without knowing them in advance. I have edited my question to try to clarify the behaviour I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Interesting question, let me have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got closer to what I was trying to achieve using the following. However I'm hoping someone could suggest a more elegant solution.

```
<style>
   .ideation-sketches {
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .outer {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   }
   .outer div {
   display: table-cell;
   }
   img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }
</style>
<div class="break-out ideation-sketches">
   <div class="outer">
      <div><img src="images/work-blue-ideation1.jpg" alt="Ideation sketches"></div>
      <div><img src="images/work-blue-ideation2.jpg" alt="More ideation sketches"></div>
      <div><img src="images/work-blue-ideation3.jpg" alt="Yet more ideation sketches"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex like so:

```css
.ideation-sketches {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.outer div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

.center img {
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="break-out ideation-sketches">
  <div class="outer">
    <!-- same size as third -->
    <div class="left"><img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Ideation sketches"></div>
    <!-- different size -->
    <div class="center"><img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200" alt="More ideation sketches"></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="https://placekitten.com/440/300" alt="Yet more ideation sketches"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, does this assume something about the relative sizes (e.g. that the outer two have the same aspect ratio?)

Comment: Try the new code css. It forces the images to go to a certain size despite the image given having different sizes

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this seems to crop the images, at least on my iPad/Safari

Comment: The behavior of the image can be modified by changing the value of the object-fit property.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gets me back to where I started; the images force the container to be wider than the max-width that I set for it. I would like them to scale down proportionally so that all three images are visible without needing to scroll horizontally. The table example achieves this but seems semantically incorrect.

Comment: You could read on [these](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_object-fit.asp) examples to learn more about the what you might want to achieve. But scaling down the image would make it sized as if none or contain were specified (would result in a smaller concrete object size). You could try out different sized placeholders with [these](https://placekitten.com/).